# What's the simplest mac docker setup for archival purposes?

Tags: macos, docker, docker-compose, docker-for-mac

I've got a bunch of old sites (wordpress/mysql/php, ruby 1.x/sqlite, etc) on my computer that I'd like to ensure easy access to in the future without having to muck up my environment.

Docker seems like the perfect candidate for this task, but I have tried to wrap my head around it many times and have realized it's time to ask for professional help (which brings me here).

I have wasted so much time messing with this thing, and have been slightly overwhelmed with depth. At first (in the case of the wp/mysql problem), I was trying to create two different images (a wordpress/php one, and a mysql one) and link them together, which appeals to my programmer-mentality of Doing It The Right Way™.

But my UX mentality has won out and I'm abandoning the Right Way™ in favor of getting this thing working in the simplest way so that *future me* (who will forget all this docker knowledge as soon as I complete this task) might be able to figure it out again.

**So here's what I want:** A docker setup that I can put in a folder along with with an exported mysql database and a wordpress site, so when I start up that badboy—*boom*—I'm browsing some old site that made a lot of sense in 2005 and makes no sense now.

Know what I'm saying? What's the simplest, future-proof way I can get this done? Is it possible to keep the data/files outside of the containers in the case I wanted to edit them? I'm using Docker For Mac.

Comment: See: https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want something really generic that's going to work for all the sites you have. That might be tricky because Docker is inherently *not* generic. You don't typically have a docker image with all the tools (PHP, Ruby, etc) to run everything. You typically build only what you need into an image.

With that being said, it might still be possible to do something like what you're asking for, and I think I can get you pointed in the right direction. The [official Wordpress](https://hub.docker.com/_/wordpress/) Docker image should be able to run your Wordpress sites. You were actually on the right track with a separate MySQL image, and this is easy to achieve with `docker-compose`.

Your docker-compose.yml file would look something like this:

```
version: '3'

services:
    wordpress:
        image: wordpress:4-php5.6-apache
        ports:
            - "8080:80"
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www/html
        environment:
            WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: mysql
            WORDPRESS_DB_USER: root
            WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: password
            WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress

    mysql:
        image: mariadb:10.1
        ports:
            - "3306:3306"
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
            MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
```

A brief summary of what that does:

- Creates 2 Docker containers, one for Wordpress and one for MySQL.
- Forwards requests from 127.0.0.1:8080 to the Wordpress container on port 80.
- Mounts `./` to `/var/www/html` in the wordpress container. Meaning it will serve Wordpress from your current directory.
- Configures environment variables so it knows how to connect to the database.
- Prepares a MySQL Docker container.
- Forwards `127.0.0.1:3306` to 3306 on the container. So you can do `mysql -u root -ppassword -h 127.0.0.1`.

Now, if you create a file called `docker-compose.yml` similar to the one above in the Wordpress directory you want to serve, you can simply run `docker-compose up` in that directory and you'll be running Wordpress in a container. If you need to restore a database dump, you can `cat dump.sql | mysql -u root -ppassword -h 127.0.0.1 WORDPRESS`. And you can access the site at `localhost:8080`. By putting a `docker-compose.yml` file like this in your projects, it would be pretty quick to spin up a container for them.

Now, because the scope of a StackOverflow answer like this is pretty limited, you'll probably run into a couple snags here and there that I didn't cover in this answer. But if you're willing to invest a little time learning more about Docker (it's really not that complex), this could be a great solution for you.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is great! It looks like everything go so close, but when I try to connect to the database it throws the classic `ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)`. Is there some other configuration I need in that compose file?

Comment: MySQL is trying to use a socket on localhost rather than TCP. Are you doing this `mysql -u root -ppassword -h localhost`? When MySQL sees `localhost` it tries to connect through `mysql.sock` rather than TCP. It should default to TCP if you do `mysql -u root -ppassword -h 127.0.0.1`. Aside from that, you might need to try forcing it with `--protocol=TCP`. If it still doesn't work, try Googling for someone having a similar problem with Docker on a Mac. I'm on Linux and the 127.0.0.1 trick works for me. Docker is forwarding `127.0.0.1:3306` to the container. But not `/tmp/mysql.sock`.

Comment: Thanks again for all this! This got me almost all the way there and cleared up some confusion. Now I'm just dealing with old wordpress issues but the containers are working as desired.

Comment: Awesome! Glad I could help out. Docker's really cool technology for that kind of thing.

Answer (score 0):

Docker for Mac and lot of PHP files (wordpress, Symfony) as mounted resources [don't like each other](https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/77) ... if You don't want to make some fancy tricks with docker-sync plus some other tricks ([since databases may be slow as well](https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/1211)).

My suggestion - if You want easy fire-and-forget is to maybe use Vagrant to setup one virtual machine which will serve all the sites? You can use [puphpet.com](https://puphpet.com) for this to easily click Your machine. There is even possibility to mark SQL files to import ... looking then on config.yml file You will know how to add additional hosts in feature and then You just fire vagrant provision to have it setted up as well.

Problem will occur if You require some old PHP or different environments/setups per site. Unfortunately Docker for Mac isn't foolproof fire-and-forget solution right now.